# How to plot (mean, SD, median, variance) histogram on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, histogram

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

allData= None
allData = pd.read_csv("football.csv")

print("mean is:",allData['Points'].mean())
print("median is:",allData['Points'].median())
print("variance is:",allData['Points'].var())
print("SD is:",allData['Points'].std())
```

I can plot all data by using:

```
allData.plot.bar()
```

the result: [image]

**My question:** Is there any possible way or build-in function that plots statistics histogram(mean, SD, median, variance) for one column(points column in my example).

the data which used inside "football.csv" as the follow:

```
Team,Games,Wins,Losses,Draws,Goals,Goals Allowed,Points
Arsenal,38,26,9,3,79,36,87
Liverpool,38,24,8,6,67,30,80
Manchester United,38,24,5,9,87,45,77
Newcastle,38,21,8,9,74,52,71
Leeds,38,18,12,8,53,37,66
Chelsea,38,17,13,8,66,38,64
West_Ham,38,15,8,15,48,57,53
Aston_Villa,38,12,14,12,46,47,50
Tottenham,38,14,8,16,49,53,50
Blackburn,38,12,10,16,55,51,46
Southampton,38,12,9,17,46,54,45
Middlesbrough,38,12,9,17,35,47,45
Fulham,38,10,14,14,36,44,44
Charlton,38,10,14,14,38,49,44
Everton,38,11,10,17,45,57,43
Bolton,38,9,13,16,44,62,40
Sunderland,38,10,10,18,29,51,40
Ipswich,38,9,9,20,41,64,36
Derby,38,8,6,24,33,63,30
Leicester,38,5,13,20,30,64,28
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be useful to plot a histogram of summary statistics for one column. Instead, you could use a histogram then add lines for the summary statistics or you could also use a plot that includes those stats, such as a box plot or violin plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# histogram with lines for summary stats
df.Points.hist()

# add your own colors and linestyles for each stat
summary_stats = (
    (5, {color}, {linestyle}),
    (10, {color}, {linestyle}),
    (15, {color}, {linestyle}),
)

for item in summary_stats:
    x, color, linestyle = item
    plt.axvline(x=x, color=color, linestyle=linestyle)

# plot a boxplot
# if you are in ipython terminal with autodiplay
# then put both commands on same line w/ semicolon
# sns.boxplot(df.Points); sns.stripplot(df.Points)
sns.boxplot(df.Points, color='lightgray')
sns.stripplot(df.Points)

# plot a violin plot
# same caveat as above for boxplot in ipython terminal
sns.violinplot(df.Points, color='lightgray')
sns.stripplot(df.Points)
```